# Open Flutter Webview link to browser

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, webview, flutterwebviewplugin

I want to ask how I can force (Android/iOS) to open external links (non domain links lets say) to browser.
I use `'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart'` > `^2.0.9` package.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a widget WebView and provide the url link for it as follows (In the plugin document):

```
return WebView(
  initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
);
```

Comment: I already have this, imagine that in this URL i have a link like 'https//www.facebook.com/account' this i want to open in on Facebook app, and not in the WebView application.

Comment: I suggest that you use this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

Answer (score 0):

if you want to open a link in new browser use [URL launcher plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)   instead of webview plugin and if you want to open link inside of your app then you can use webview like :

```
return WebView(
 initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
 );
```